# Mongo GeoJSON Compliancy

Tags: ogc, mongodb, compliance

Does MongoDB follow OGC compliancy standards for GeoJSON objects, or some other standard?

I have not been able to find a direct statement on this. A follow up to this is whether there are any tools/methods for taking a GeoJSON object and converting it to be compliant with the standard that Mongo uses?

Comment: See my answer to your previous question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238977/problem-adding-geojson-to-mongodb-loop-shares-more-than-one-vertex-with-its-par/239102#239102. I do not know for sure but I suppose that MongoDB wants valid geometries as they are defined in OGC Simple Feature standard.